# LiveData observeForever not updating with the room changes

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

following observeForever not giving any data when
    - User is logged out (There is no user in the database)
    - Login and insert a user into the db. (Here observeForever is not being triggered)

```
mUserDao.getCompleteUser().observeForever(this::updateCompleteUser);
```

**DAO**

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao extends BaseDao<User> {
@Query("SELECT * FROM user")
@Transaction
LiveData<CompleteUser> getCompleteUser();
}
```

But `@Query("SELECT * FROM user")
     @Transaction
     Flowable<CompleteUser> getCompleteUser();`

is working which does not return null for the logged-out state (expected behavior)

**User**

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    String uid;

    String email;
}
```

**Complete User**

```
public class CompleteUser {
    @Embedded
    User user;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "uid", entityColumn = "userId", entity = Address.class)
    List<Address> addresses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a `User` with `List<Address>`, you can check out [this](https://proandroiddev.com/android-room-handling-relations-using-livedata-2d892e40bd53) to have a look at handling such a relation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but even the LiveData<User> getUser(); is not working. my room lib version is 1.1.1. The link you provided is an alternative to the @Reference feature of the room. I want to do with the same.

Comment: But the same thing is working for LiveData<T> getT();

Comment: try `androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01` and `kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0-rc01`

Comment: Flowable<List<CompleteUser>> getUsers(); is working for every case and it's easy to convert a list to a single item. androidx libs are causing failures.

Comment: you mean `Flowable<List<CompleteUser>>` works but `LiveData<List<CompleteUser>>` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes. I'm using observeForever inside the constructor of the repository. Also, I have enabled the allowMainThreadQueries for the room database.